# pandas inserting rows in a monotonically increasing dataframe using itertuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been searching for a solution to this for a while, and I'm really stuck! I have a very large text file, imported as a panda dataframe containing just two columns but with hundreds of thousands to millions of rows. The columns contain packet dumps: one is the data of the packets formatted as ascii representations of monotonically increasing integers, and the second the packet time. 
I want to go through this dataframe, and make sure that the dataframe is monotonically increasing, and if there are missing data, to insert a new rows in order to make the list monotonically increasing. i.e the 'data' column should be filled in with the appropriate value but the time should be changed to 'NaN' or 'NULL', etc.

The following is a sample of the data:

```
              data  frame_time_epoch
303030303030303000  1527986052.485855896
303030303030303100  1527986052.491020305
303030303030303200  1527986052.496127062
303030303030303300  1527986052.501301944
303030303030303400  1527986052.506439335
```

So I have two questions:

1) I've been trying to loop through the dataframe using itertuples to try to get the next row do a comparison with the current row and if the difference s more than the 100 to add a new row, but unfortunately I've struggled with this since, there doesn't seem to be a good way to retreive the row after the one called.

2) Is there a better way (faster) way to do this other than the way I've proposed?

This may be trivial, though I've really struggled with it. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem at a time. You can do a verbatim check `df.data.is_monotonic_increasing`.

Inserting new indices: it is better to go the other way around. You already know the index you want. It is given by `range(min_val, max_val+1, 100)`. You can create a blank DataFrame with this index and update it using your data.

This may be memory intensive so you may need to go over your data in chunks. In that case, you may need to provide index range ahead of time.

```
import pandas as pd

# test data
df = pd.read_csv(
    pd.compat.StringIO(
        """data  frame_time_epoch
303030303030303000  1527986052.485855896
303030303030303100  1527986052.491020305
303030303030303200  1527986052.496127062
303030303030303300  1527986052.501301944
303030303030303500  1527986052.506439335"""
    ),
    sep=r" +",
)

# check if the data is increasing
assert df.data.is_monotonic_increasing

# desired index range
rng = range(df.data.iloc[0], df.data.iloc[-1] + 1, 100)

# blank frame with full index
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=rng, columns=["frame_time_epoch"])
# update with existing data
df2.update(df.set_index("data"))

# result
# frame_time_epoch
# 303030303030303000      1.52799e+09
# 303030303030303100      1.52799e+09
# 303030303030303200      1.52799e+09
# 303030303030303300      1.52799e+09
# 303030303030303400              NaN
# 303030303030303500      1.52799e+09
```

Comment: it took me a while before I realized what you were doing, but when I figured it out, I thought it was a brilliant way to approach this problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just for examination: Did you try sth like

```
delta = df['data'].diff()
delta[delta>0]
delta[delta<100]
```

Comment: I hadn't though, now that I've tried it, it turns out that since the data is in ascii characters, I'll have to strip out every other 3 in the series first, before attempting this, as this produces results of 9100 for every 10th item in the list. Thank you for your response. Do you have any suggestions on calling the next row using itertuples btw?

Comment: Look at the answer of Yakim Pirozhenko - it was faster and very much more complete.